# State Management Error using Provider in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have run into issues with managing state using Provider in Flutter. I'm triggering a certain API action in the `manageLeaves` function which supposedly invokes another API function `getRecords` upon a success response. However, the states related to these functions don't seem to update on both the `manageLeaves` and `getRecords` functions. Here are the `manageLeaves` and the `getRecords` functions.

ManageLeaves Function(The `_pendingLeaves` List doesn't seem to update. The `getLeaveRequest` function is what populates the `_pendingLeaves`, `_approvedLeaves` and `_rejectedLeaves` with data based on the response received from API.)

```
//I need the states of _pendingLeaves, _approvedLeaves and _rejectedLeaves updated
List<Map<String, dynamic>> _pendingLeaves = [];         
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> _approvedLeaves = [];
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> _rejectedLeaves = [];
  

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> get pendingLeaves {
    return [..._pendingLeaves];
  }

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> get approvedLeaves {
    return [..._approvedLeaves];
  }

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> get rejectedLeaves {
    return [..._rejectedLeaves];
  }

  //This is the initial API that populates data into these variables
  Future<void> getLeaveRequest(String fromDate, String toDate) async {
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    print('From Date: $fromDate');
    print('To Date: $toDate');

    _pendingLeaves = [];
    _approvedLeaves = [];
    _rejectedLeaves = [];

    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(AppUrl.viewLeaveManager),
        body: json.encode({'from_date': fromDate, 'to_date': toDate}),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ${localStorage.getString('token')}'
        });

    if (response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode <= 300) {
      _leaveList = json.decode(response.body);
      for (int i = 0; i < _leaveList['data'].length; i++) {
        if (_leaveList['data'][i]['status'] == 0) {
          _pendingLeaves.add(_leaveList['data'][i]);
        } else if (_leaveList['data'][i]['status'] == 1) {
          _approvedLeaves.add(_leaveList['data'][i]);
        } else {
          _rejectedLeaves.add(_leaveList['data'][i]);
        }
      }
    } else {
      _leaveList = json.decode(response.body);

      // _leaveList = {};
    }
    print('LEAVE REQUESTS: $_leaveList');

    print('PENDING REQUESTS: $_pendingLeaves');

    notifyListeners();
  }
  
  //The `manageLeaves` API call is supposed to recall both the `getLeaveRequest` and `getRecords` API call to update the states
  Future<dynamic> manageLeaves(int id, int status, BuildContext context,
      Map<String, dynamic> data, String fromDate, String toDate) async {
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    DateTime date = DateTime.parse(data['created_at']);

      String month = date.month.toString();
      String year = date.year.toString();


    print('ID: $id');
    print('Status: $status');

    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(AppUrl.leaveManager),
        body: json.encode({'id': id, 'status': status}),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ${localStorage.getString('token')}'
        });

    if (response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode <= 300) {
      _leaveResponse = json.decode(response.body);

      print('RESPONSEEEEEEEEE: $_leaveResponse');

        Provider.of<ReportingTreeViewModel>(context, listen: false).getRecords(id, month, year, context);     //The getRecords API Call. The code for the same is just below this snippet


      if (status == 1) {
        _approvedLeaves.add(data);

        _pendingLeaves.removeWhere((value) => value['leave_id'] == id);

        Provider.of<LeaveRequestViewModel>(context, listen: false).getLeaveRequest(fromDate, toDate);      //The getLeaveRequest API Call


        Flushbar(
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 4),
          flushbarPosition: FlushbarPosition.BOTTOM,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          icon: const Icon(Icons.error, color: Colors.white),
          message: _leaveResponse['data'],
          barBlur: 20,
        ).show(context);
      } else {
        _leaveResponse = json.decode(response.body);

        print(' REJECCCCCT RESPONSEEEEEEEEE: $_leaveResponse');
        _rejectedLeaves.add(data);
        _pendingLeaves.removeWhere((value) => value['leave_id'] == id);


        Provider.of<LeaveRequestViewModel>(context, listen: false).getLeaveRequest(fromDate, toDate);

        Provider.of<ReportingTreeViewModel>(context, listen: false).getRecords(id, month, year, context);


        Flushbar(
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 4),
          flushbarPosition: FlushbarPosition.BOTTOM,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          icon: const Icon(Icons.error, color: Colors.white),
          // margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(100, 10, 100, 0),
          title: 'Leave Rejected',
          message: _leaveResponse['data'],
          barBlur: 20,
        ).show(context);
        
      }
    } else {
      _leaveResponse = json.decode(response.body);

      print('ERRRORR RESPONSEEEEEEEEE: $_leaveResponse');
      
      Flushbar(
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 4),
        flushbarPosition: FlushbarPosition.BOTTOM,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        icon: const Icon(Icons.error, color: Colors.white),
        // margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(100, 10, 100, 0),
        title: 'Error Occured',
        message: '',
        barBlur: 20,
      ).show(context);
      

      _leaveResponse = {};
    }
    print('Leave Manager: $_leaveResponse');
    print('Approved Leave: $_approvedLeaves');
    print('Approved Leave: $_rejectedLeaves');

    notifyListeners();
    return _leaveResponse;
  }
```

The `getRecords` API function

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> _allLeaves = [];       //This is what I need updating here

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> get allLeaves {
    return [..._allLeaves];
  }

  Future<void> getRecords(
      int id, String month, String year, BuildContext context) async {
    _report = {};

    _allLeaves = [];

    print('IDDDDDDDDDDDd: $id');

    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(AppUrl.employeeRecord),
        body: json.encode({'id': id, 'month': month, 'year': year}),
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ${localStorage.getString('token')}',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        });

    if (response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode <= 300) {
      _report = json.decode(response.body);

      for (int i = 0; i < _report['leave'].length; i++) {
        _allLeaves.add(_report['leave'][i]);
      }

      print('ALL LEAVESSSSSS: $_allLeaves');
    } else {
      _report = {};
      Flushbar(
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 4),
        flushbarPosition: FlushbarPosition.BOTTOM,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        icon: const Icon(Icons.error, color: Colors.white),
        // margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(100, 10, 100, 0),
        // title: 'An Error Occured',
        message: 'An Error Occured',
        barBlur: 20,
      ).show(context);
    }
    print('Employee Record: $_report');
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Please note that my idea of State Management has always been to recall the very API's that are responsible for populating data and repopulating them with the updated data from the API response. Feel free to share your thoughts on this approach and also provide a possible solution to my code above.